# How to get wordpress post tags using fishpig in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, third-party-module, wordpress, tags

I am using fishpig magento extension and everything is working perfectly.

I am fetching posts using the code

> $posts = $this->getPosts();

and I need `tags associated with each post`.

Answer (score 0):

> You can get the tags for an individual post by calling the **getTags** method on the post object.

```
<?php $posts = $this->getPosts(); ?>
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
    <?php $tags = $post->getTags() ?>
    <?php if (count($tags) > 0): ?>
        <span><?php echo (count($categories) == 0) ? $this->__('This post was tagged with') : $this->__('and was tagged with') ?> </span> 
        <?php $it = count($tags) ?>
        <?php foreach($tags as $tag): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $tag->getUrl() ?>">
                <?php echo $tag->getName() ?>
            </a><?php if (--$it > 0): ?>, <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```